# Build tool for c# similar to maven/gradle for java

Tags: c#, python, .net, gradle, msbuild

Am pretty new to c#(Basically Java Developer). We've a requirement to generate the c# solution (dll) programmatically.

**Folder Structure**

```
Root

  |-- model

         |     |--- A.cs
         |     |--- B.cs

  |-- service

        |     |---- AService.cs
        |     |---- BService.cs
```

Assume We've cs files present in a folder called root as above. We need to create a dll for the above using programmatic way.

1. What's the best preferred way of doing it? (A sample code will be preferable if any)
2. Can't we generate the c# dll using python (or) some other language if we've the cs files?

**I need something like build tool(gradle/maven), which takes all the files and generate a jar in java. Am looking to generate the dll using cs files in the same manner**

While trying to find out solutions for the same found below options but am looking for a recommended way of doing it:

1. c# Project Templates
2. c# Add-ins

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: If you have the `.cs` files, you need a compiler.

Comment: Assume .cs files are properly compiled and can be copied directly to a solution/dll

Comment: Have a look at the `CSharpCodeProvider` class.  You can call the C# compiler from code.

Comment: Can you add some more detail about what problem you're trying to solve? Are you looking for something like a build controller that can compile your code without someone actually clicking Build in VS? Do you need to compile source files at runtime that are unknown at build time?

Comment: Yes, I have around 100-200 files present in nested folders I need to compile them and build a dll file with out touching VS if possible.

Comment: Eg:- I need something like build tool(gradle/maven), which takes all the files and generate a jar in java. Am looking to generate the dll using the cs files in the same manner

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Command-line Building With csc.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx)